# mysql database comparison before insert

Tags: php, mysql, database, scrape

So I am scraping a site for urls and storing these urls in a db I am looking for the lightest way to compare the new scraped urls with the urls stored to only add the ones that arent currently stored in the db. I am working in php with a mysql db.

Comment: Can you provide the code you have attempted thus far?

Comment: Give the URL field a `UNIQUE` index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the URL a `UNIQUE` index. In your query :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table (field1,field2) VALUES ('value1','value2')
```

This will skip the url when they already exist in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using phpmyadmin to administrate the databse?

In any case, in order for this to be fast, you need to create an "index" over the column that contains the url. If you want to be sure that only unique urls are stored there, use a "unqiue index".

Comment: what does phpmyadmin have to do with this? adding an index does NOT require it. you can do it from pretty much anything that can issue a query, including the command line.

Comment: Considering that the user does not appear to know about indexes, it seems to me a tool like phpmyadmin would be helpful.